# Setting source port on udp socket

Tags: java, sockets

We've developed a Java application that sends several UDP datagrams to the very same destination IP address. Obviously the destination port is always the same one, but we can't seem to be able to set the source port to remain the same on each datagram. 
If the data package we send is bigger than MTU the package is properly splitted over the same source port, but once we send a new data package the source port changes, generating a new firewall session (which network admin has warned us to be very bad due to the amount of sessions the application is generating).

Right now we're sending the packages with the following statement:

We've tried several approaches and the result is always the same, we can't seem to be able to set the source port to a fixed value.

Edit- pasting actual code:

```
private boolean sendImage(byte[] imageData, InetAddress address,
int port) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException {

    boolean ret = false;


    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(imageData, imageData.length, address, PUERTO_UDP);
        socket.send(dp);
        ret = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Main.lanzarExcepcion(e);
        ret = false;
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
             socket.close();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: hmmm i suppose that the port changes in the time that the previous UDP socket is not close , so the OS is trying to open a new connection so the previous port is not yet available and opens up the next available. Is that your issue ? because i cant think any other reason that changes the client's port. Also could you explain what '*but once we send a new data package the source port changes* ' means ? how are you trying to open the new connection ? In the same Thread? In another process ?? how are you closing the UDP socket?

Comment: Also your initialization for the `DatagramPacket` class , doesnt look so proper......not even sure if that gets compiled at all

Comment: The way to keep it always the same is to always send from the same socket, instead of evidently creating a new socket per request.

Comment: ok the issue is the one i noted , check my answer

Comment: Just tried to leave the DatagramSocket object open and reusing it just calling 
    socket.send(dp)
and commented  out the 
    socket.close() 

Still the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are closing the actual `DatagramSocket` instead of reusing the same , and simply call `socket.send(DatagramPacket)`. If you cant keep the client socket open , then you could even define the clients port like : `DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(9743);` so each time you are calling a new clientSocket , it will get the same port or it will throw a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind`

This will not solve the network sessions issue, because you are opening a new UDP Socket. Also i suspect that your network admin , sees the previous sessions , because you are not closing the UDP Sockets at all , but simply spawning them

Comment: Just tried to leave the DatagramSocket object open and reusing it just calling socket.send(dp) and commented out the socket.close() Still the same behaviour. Had some hope in this approach since it makes sense

Comment: you dont reopen the socket? could you try also defining the port as well?

Comment: Just managed to make it work by both not closing the socket and specifying the desired port, now i'm getting the proper src port!

Comment: ok thats cool. Could you post also if the network sessions issue got resolved too?

Comment: Confirmed that the network sessions went down from 30k per classroom in 15mins to 30 :D

Comment: @CarlosAlbaladejo :). ok glad it got resolved. IO resources monitoring can be a pain in the ass , especially when the app uses a lot of native IO calls

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @AntJavaDev

The solution was to:

1.- keep the DatagramSocket open
2.- pass src port in the arguments
3.- reusing the unclosed DatagramSocket for every new data packet to the same destination!

Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

The source port is an ephemeral port, generated for you by the underlying networking implementation. There is no reason to set it to a particular port number.

Comment: Actually i just wrote you the reason, we're eating 2K sessions per client each 15 mins out of 2M maximum sessions of the firewall resources.
We are in a university with 1700 accesable clients, if everyone started using this software we'd leave the firewall unstable.

Comment: @CarlosAlbaladejo Have you tried using the same `InetSocketAddress` object for many UDP packets, rather than creating a new one per UDP packet.?